# Refactoring function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Me need get html one element and overwrite other element. I have this function:

```
function ratings() {
  const divInWrapper = document.getElementById("auto-mag-id");
  const shortcode = document.getElementById("auto-mag");
  divInWrapper.innerHTML = shortcode.innerHTML;

  const divInWrapper2 = document.getElementById("karat-id");
  const shortcode2 = document.getElementById("karat");
  divInWrapper2.innerHTML = shortcode2.innerHTML;

  const divInWrapper3 = document.getElementById("zebra-id");
  const shortcode3 = document.getElementById("zebra");
  divInWrapper3.innerHTML = shortcode3.innerHTML;
}
```

on page be a lot of this elements, how can refactor this function, maybe this "for"?

Example HTML

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, at?</div>
    <div id="auto-mag-id">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div id="karat-id">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div id="zebra-id">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, at?</div>
    <div id="auto-mag">Need this text in div this id auto-mag-id</div>
    <div id="karat">Need this text in div this id karat-id</div>
    <div id="zebra">Need this text in div this id zebra-id</div>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, at?</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML markup that this code runs on? I'm sure there's a better way

Comment: Don't use a `for`, or any other type of loop for this. The best approach is to structure your HTML in a common manner and use classes on it. Then you can traverse the DOM to relate elements to each other. If you need a demonstration of how to do this, please add all the relevant HTML to the question

Comment: @CertainPerformance im add example html

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

Can be done safer with the use of a relevant class or data attribute

```js
const ratings = () => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll("[id$='-id']")].forEach(divInWrapper => {
    console.log(divInWrapper.id.split("-id")[0])
    const shortcode = document.getElementById(divInWrapper.id.split("-id")[0]);
    divInWrapper.innerHTML = shortcode.innerHTML;
  });
};
ratings()
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, at?</div>
<div id="auto-mag-id">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div id="karat-id">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div id="zebra-id">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, at?</div>
<div id="auto-mag">Need this text in div this id auto-mag-id</div>
<div id="karat">Need this text in div this id karat-id</div>
<div id="zebra">Need this text in div this id zebra-id</div>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, at?</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd refactor the HTML so that the `id` elements are all in one container, and the target elements are in a different container. Then all you have to do is iterate over the indicies of the children:

```js
const targetContainer = document.querySelector('.target-container');
document.querySelectorAll('.orig-container > div').forEach((div, i) => {
  targetContainer.children[i].textContent = div.textContent;
});
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, at?</div>
<div class='orig-container'>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 3.</div>
</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, at?</div>
<div class='target-container'>
  <div id="auto-mag">Need this text in div this id auto-mag-id</div>
  <div id="karat">Need this text in div this id karat-id</div>
  <div id="zebra">Need this text in div this id zebra-id</div>
</div>
```